# New line missing when transform xml using apache transformer

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I followed [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-create-xml-file-in-java-dom/) example for how to write `XML`.  It works okay but the problem is when I replace this line:

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
```

with the transformer used in my web application:

```
org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl
```

then the `XML` starts with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

This is problem because I can't validate it. `xs:schema` should be on a new line.  Is there option that I can use to fix it and still use this transformer?

Comment: Please explain "problem because I cant validate it". The described XML is perfectly valid.

Comment: not it isnt I post just 1. line and xs:schema has no end tag. It is because of error: "Content is not allowed in prolog." . But this is not part of question. I need it to new line because for formating.

Comment: Try this : `transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT,"yes");`

Comment: I try it but 1. line is still no formated

Comment: @hudi having the xml declaration on the same line as everything else shouldn't cause any issues and is perfectly valid XML. The issue is caused by something else. Maybe its your encoding? Try changing it to `UTF-16` or look for other areas where using the different transformer might be an issue.

Comment: and how I can change encoding ?

Answer (score 0):

you can ask the transformer not to add xml declaration:

```
transformer.setOutputProperty("omit-xml-declaration", "yes");
```

this might solve your problem